# How can I forward a meeting request in Outlook 2010 only when I have accepted it?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, meetings

We have just migrated to Outlook 2010 (from Groupwise) and I want to be able to set it up so once I have accepted a meeting request manually in Outlook it automatically forwards it to another email address.

Any ideas how to do this? I am guessing I need some form of VBA that acts on the event of meeting accepted but I have no ideas beyond that.